# How do I define size of C++ Vector in a Parameterised Constructor

Tags: c++

I want to initialize my vector to it's size (in this case - 5) from a parameterised constructor
which I'll be calling from the main function.

```
class OrderedStream{
  public:
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
   OrderedStream(int n)
   {
     vec(n); // define size of vector here 
   }
};

int main()
{
  OrderedStream *o = new OrderedStream(5);
  // By now, I want a vector of size 5
}
```

Comment: See your C++ textbook for more information on using member initialization lists, which is how you do this in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *member initializer list*:

```
OrderedStream(int n)
    : vec(n)  // <- A list of initializers for (non-static) members
{
    // Empty
}
```

---

On another note, unless you expect negative sizes, I recommend that you use `size_t` for sizes.